# Can I run a corny keg without liquid post?

Tags: corny-keg

So I was starting to setup a jockey box and cornelius pin-lock kegs to enjoy my last batch, when I noticed that I was without my pin lock liquid quick disconnect. Well, a friend brought one, and then everything went right, but before that, I was thinking if I could run the sistem without it.

My beer was already carbonated, and my plan was to bleed off the CO2, and them remove the liquid post of my keg, resulting in expose the threaded fitting of the keg itself. Then fit the hose with a hose clamp and then put the CO2 again and run the system.

Would this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work.  I think that the length of the threading isn't much.  It might not even be as tall as a standard hose clamp so there isn't much to 'grab' onto.  But it doesn't hurt to try.  You might be able to find female threaded hose barb you could but on there too give you a better tube connection.

Comment: Thanks, it is just what I was thinking about... If the clamp has enough place to be. But after that I think that if I remove the poppet valve from the post and screw it again, then I could put a larger hose 'grabing' the whole post. Well, not a good way to choose, but its good to just know it just in case... Thanks again, brewchez.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a hard time picturing what you're talking about, but it should work as long as you have the two key components:

1. A pick-up tube that goes to the bottom of the keg
2. A seal good enough to withstand the pressure of the co2

Comment: I still have the liquid diptube conecting the top to the bottom of the keg. This cover what are you talking about in the first topic?

Comment: That should do it.